# Django form are not showing in html template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a form in Django template but it is just not showing the fields

here is my files

**models.py** where i created the desired table

```
class ReportMessage(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name="report_message_sender", on_delete='CASCADE')
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete='CASCADE')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    reason = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms.py** where i created the form to edit only one field in the table

```
class ReportMessageForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = ReportMessage
        fields = ['reason', ]
```

**views.py** where i created the view for the form

```
@login_required
def report_message(request, pk):
    current_user = request.user
    reported_message = get_object_or_404(Message, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        report_message_form = ReportMessageForm(request.POST)
        if report_message_form.is_valid():
            model_instance = report_message_form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.sender = current_user
            model_instance.message = reported_message
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('report_confirm')
    else:
        report_message_form = ReportMessageForm()

    context = {
        'report_message_form': report_message_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/report_message.html', context)


def report_confirm(request):
    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/report_confirm.html')
```

and **urls.py** where the urls i used for the views

```
path('report/messages/<int:pk>/', views.report_message, name="report_message"),
path('report/confirm', views.report_confirm, name="report_confirm"),
```

and finally that is how i used the form in the **html** template

```
{% extends 'fostania_web_app/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
     <form action="" method="post" name="ReportMessageForm" align="right">
         {% csrf_token %}
{{ report_message_form }}
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100px;" value="إرسال" />
     </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and then all what i see in the html page is the submit button and there is no form labels or input or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your forms.py if you are not using ModelForm then you have to explicitly  declare the fields for the forms

```
reason = forms.Charfield()
```

Or you can use ModelForm which inherits from the model you specify.

You should specify the model in the Meta class while using ModelForm.You can also specify required fields from the Model in the fields list in Meta class

```
Class myform(forms.ModelForm)
   Class Meta:
      model = your_model_name
      fields= [reason,]
```

Cheers
:)

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is in your model form because you are using forms.Form and you need to use forms.ModelForm

```
class ReportMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = ReportMessage
      fields = ['reason', ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def report_confirm(request):
    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/report_confirm.html', context) #add the context
```

You need to pass in the "context" so that it shows in the template